# Iterate through hasmap and use key value

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm trying to iterate through a hashmap and and use the key during my iteration. I decided to use it inside an Async Task because the iteration was blocking my UI thread.

My hashmap has LatLng as the Key and a Marker as the Object, when I get the key during Iteration and pass it to a new LatLng that works fine but when I try to use this new LatLng I get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` exception. Strangely this doesn't happen when I use the code without the AsyncTask

Here is my code

```
    class AddCityMarker extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(Integer... counter) {           

        //CityMarker cMarker;
        LatLng marker_loc;

        List<String> city_markers = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(displayed.size() > 0){

            Iterator<HashMap.Entry<LatLng, Marker>> myIterator = displayed.entrySet().iterator();
            while(myIterator.hasNext()) {
                //cMarker = new CityMarker();
                HashMap.Entry<LatLng, Marker> entry = myIterator.next();                    
                marker_loc = entry.getKey();

                Log.i("ZOOM", "Key = " + marker_loc + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());

                List<Address> addresses = null;                     
                try {
                  //This is where I get the error
                    addresses = gcode.getFromLocation(marker_loc.latitude, marker_loc.longitude, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(addresses.size() > 0) {  
                    if(!city_markers.contains(addresses.get(0).getLocality())){
                        city_markers.add(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                        //map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker_loc).snippet("CITY"));
                    }                           
                }
            }                   
        }


        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonResult) {

        try {   

            if(isClubMarkers){
                map.clear();
                isClubMarkers = false;
            }
            displayed.clear();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens into gcode.getFromLocation? Did you modify displayed.entrySet()?

Comment: no, I'm not modifying the set at all execept on PostExecute. I'm just using the value of Key to place markers on map

Comment: "to place markers on map" which modify displayed.entrySet() at the end?

Comment: `ConcurrentModification` means that you do modify it. I.e. the `.next()` element is no longer what `Iterator` expected. Can either be that the Ui thread modifies it while `AsyncTask` iterates in a background thread or vice versa.

Comment: No, I do all operation in the same function depending on zoom level. The part of the code I have displayed is when zoom is at 8 then I just clear map with map.clear() and then do the above.

Comment: Possible that you start that `AsyncTask` on a regular basis? One ending task clears the map while next one iterates over it?

Comment: I will monitor how many times Aysnc Task is being called and also the displayed data set.

Comment: Quick fix: if it is a `Map` that causes this, try `ConcurrentHashMap` which guarantees not to crash with `ConcurrentModificationException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android 1.6 to Android HoneyComb, the async tasks are running in parallel mode. That means like different threads. Some times in your case, you might be calling the async task more than one time and they may try to access the same HashMap for the itteration. You can avoid this exception by using "ConcurrentHashMap" instead of HashMap. But the proper way is to identify whether the async task is calling more than once and try to avoid it if its there. This can also happen if you tries to operate with the Hashmap when the Async task itterates though the same. If thats the case use "ConcurrentHashMap" which is thread safe.